# Proof and problem solving - set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, problem-solving

Prove that $(A\Delta C)\backslash B = (A\backslash (B \cup C))\cup (C\backslash (A\cup B))$.

I tried with an $x$ that can be in $(A\Delta C)\backslash B$, so $x$ is in $A \Delta C$ but not in $B$.
If $x$ is in $A \Delta C$, it can be in $A$ or $C$.
If it's in $A$, it's not in $B \cup C$, that means $x$ is in $A\backslash (B\cup C)$.
I use the same idea and I can prove it's in $C\backslash A\cup B$, but I just don't know how to get the union of those two solutions.
The opposite implication also needs to be proved.

Thank you!

Comment: What is $A(B\cup C)$? Does it mean $A\cap(B\cup C)$?

Comment: It's supposed to be a difference, A\ B∪C.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! I have edited your post to make it look nicer. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remark that for any two sets $X,Y$, if $x \in X$, then $x \in X \cup Y$. Using this, you can conclude that in both of your cases, the element is in $(A\backslash (B \cup C))\cup (C\backslash (A\cup B))$.

Answer (score 2):

$$(A\Delta C)\backslash B = $$

$$((A \cap C^C) \cup (A^C \cap C)) \setminus B =$$

$$((A \cap C^C) \cup (A^C \cap C)) \cap B^C =$$

$$(A \cap C^C \cap B^C) \cup (A^C \cap C \cap B^C) =$$

$$(A \cap B^C \cap C^C) \cup (C \cap A^C \cap B^C) =$$

$$(A \cap (B \cup C)^C) \cup (C \cap (A \cap B)^C) =$$

$$(A\backslash (B \cup C))\cup (C\backslash (A\cup B))$$

Comment: We still haven't learned doing it that way, but it is really helpful. Thank you!

Comment: @haus Yeah, once you learn the algebra for this, you don't want to go back to the 'Let $x \in ...$ ...' proofs ... but given as you haven't learned the algebra yet, you'll have to do exactly the  'Let $x \in ...$ ...'  method. And, like you say, you will probably have to go both ways, unless you can do it all in terms of 'if and only if's

Comment: It's worth noting that in general, the complement operator isn't well-defined. We could just define it to be the complement of the set in $A\cup B \cup C$ or something, but otherwise it's not well defined.

Comment: @Sambo True ... but for 'naive set theory' like this it works like a charm! :)  And like you say, if someone wants to be nitpicky about it, just consider the union of all involved sets combined as the 'Universe'